# SpringData custom JPA queries location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to change the default location of JPA queries (which is /META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties) into jpa-named-queries.properties (the file will be just under resources folder). With default location everything works fine but with custom location queries cannot be localized. I am setting new location via JavaConfig:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:jpa-named-queries.properties")
public interface AppConf {
}
```

What else is needed to make it works?

Thanks for replies.

Adam

Comment: which version of spring-data-commons-core and spring-data-jpa are you using.Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: I am using spring-data-jpa version 1.11.1.RELEASE and spring-data-commons version 1.13.1.RELEASE. Using class instead of interface fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use class instead of interface.