# How to get native query from spring cloud config server properties file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-cloud-config

I have a requirement to keep the SQL queries outside source code. 
I know I can keep the queries in jpa-named-queries.properties inside META-INF folder but can we load this from config server? Or is it need to be inside spring boot jar?

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615001/spring-data-jpa-using-property-in-query-as-parameter/58615272#58615272

Comment: Thank you for the link. We are already using this pattern already in few cases. But what I want here is to put entire query in property file and reference it in repository like @Query(value="${example.query}")

Comment: You can check the link how you can achievement, I added `UPDATED`  as an alternative to do what you want to do, if that answer helps you, please upvote it as answer.. thanks!

Comment: I think this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018164/springdata-custom-jpa-queries-location